# Get sum from the nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have below array of objects. As you can see, there is a nested object named `count` in each of these objects. I want to get total of `Closed`, `Verify` and `Analyze`

For e.g. the total of `Closed` is 23, `Verify` is 3 and `Analyze` is 20

```
"byPerson": [
      {
        "personId": "973567318",
        "firstName": "Others",
        "lastName": "",
        "count": {
          "Closed": 7,
          "Verify": 3,
          "Analyze": 19
        }
      },
      {
        "personId": "1514903899",
        "firstName": "Yatish",
        "lastName": "Patel",
        "count": {
          "Closed": 16,
          "Analyze": 1
        }
      }
 ]
```

I tried this way but it didnt work. for e.g to get total of `Closed`

```
cosnt result = data.reduce((a, b) => ({"Closed": a.count["Closed"] + b.count["Closed"]}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the data into an object with the keys for the nested properties you want to total. In the reduce callback destructure the "totals" properties and the nested `count` property and compute the summation.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "personId": "973567318",
    "firstName": "Others",
    "lastName": "",
    "count": {
      "Closed": 7,
      "Verify": 3,
      "Analyze": 19
    }
  },
  {
    "personId": "1514903899",
    "firstName": "Yatish",
    "lastName": "Patel",
    "count": {
      "Closed": 16,
      "Analyze": 1
    }
  }
];

const totalCount = data.reduce(({
  Closed,
  Analyze,
  Verify
}, {
  count
}) => ({
  Closed: Closed + (count?.Closed || 0),
  Analyze: Analyze + (count?.Analyze || 0),
  Verify: Verify + (count?.Verify || 0),
}), {
  Closed: 0,
  Analyze: 0,
  Verify: 0,
});

console.log(totalCount);
```

Comment: Resse- i ran the code snippet but it gave me error.

Comment: @ArenTrot Ack, the "tidy" button changed the syntax. Sorry about that, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Resse- When i use this code, it tells me data.reduce is not a function

Comment: It returns 23, 20, 0, not 23, 20, 3

Comment: @ArenTrot I named the array `data` in my snippet, it may have a different name in your actual code.

Comment: @almarc Thanks, it was an order of precedence, should be resolved. Should have caught that myself. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

```js
const byPerson = [
      {
        "personId": "973567318",
        "firstName": "Others",
        "lastName": "",
        "count": {
          "Closed": 7,
          "Verify": 3,
          "Analyze": 19
        }
      },
      {
        "personId": "1514903899",
        "firstName": "Yatish",
        "lastName": "Patel",
        "count": {
          "Closed": 16,
          "Analyze": 1
        }
      }
 ];
const sum = byPerson.reduce((agg, item) => {
  ['Closed', 'Verify', 'Analyze'].forEach(f => agg[f] += item.count[f] || 0);
  return agg;
}, {Closed: 0, Verify: 0, Analyze: 0});
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is  a case where you really don't even need reduce and can use a simple loop as well as iterate the `Object.keys()`

```js
const byPerson = [
      {
        "personId": "973567318",
        "firstName": "Others",
        "lastName": "",
        "count": {
          "Closed": 7,
          "Verify": 3,
          "Analyze": 19
        }
      },
      {
        "personId": "1514903899",
        "firstName": "Yatish",
        "lastName": "Patel",
        "count": {
          "Closed": 16,
          "Analyze": 1
        }
      }
 ];
 
const sum =  {Closed: 0, Verify: 0, Analyze: 0}

byPerson.forEach(({count})=> {
   Object.keys(sum).forEach(k => sum[k] += (count[k] || 0))
});
 

console.log(sum);
```